# Java Relative URL for URL class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a file in my working project. It's in the current directory of source code.

```
Main
   -> src
       [packeges]
   -> plugin
        ->MyLib.jar
   -> other
```

I have a class in a packege of the src folder. Now I want to load the jar file to URL class like,

```
new URL("jar:file:/./plugin/MyLib.jar!/") // this relative file path is wrong
```

Could you please tell me what is the corrent relative path here?

Comment: What is your current working directory? Have you tried without the slash after `file:`?

Comment: @Thilo It's a Netbeans project. And I tried without slash. Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that "." refers to the current directory of your binaries (*.class), not of your  source code. Try create a url relative to your binaries.